# input type checkbox vs asp:checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Can someone explain this reaction. I try to dynamically put an asp:checkbox in the CS file. I don't see it on the page. compared to the input type checkbox that works fine.

What is my issue?

Here are the 2 lines:

```
Response.Write("    <div class='userList'><input type='checkbox' id='chk' value='" + row["id"].ToString() + "' "+ isChecked +" /></div>");
Response.Write("    <div class='userList'><asp:CheckBox ID='Cb' runat='server' /></div>");
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net controls must be compiled by the ASP.Net pipeline to html. Response.Write write direct to the output. So you send `asp:CheckBox` direct to the browser. The asp.net pipeline will compile `asp:CheckBox` to `<input type="checkbox"` if you embed it in an .ascx or .aspx file.

Comment: Simple enough. Would it be best practice to use the input type checkbox in the response.write or would you suggest something better?

Comment: If you want to work with dynamic Controls or some thing, take a look at `LiteralControl`.